# Make sure runtime Java superclass is correct

Tags: java, inheritance, jvm

This coming from a real world example, some Hibernate class subclasses an Antlr class and attempts to populate some field, which was only introduced in a recent Antlr version.

```
HibernateClass ---subclasses---> AntlrClass
HibernateClass uses AntlrClass.fieldX
```

If someone deploys at runtime an older Antlr library, this superclass field will not exist and a `NoSuchFieldError` will be thrown.

What is the standard Java/JVM way to make sure that the superclass you are dynamically binding to at runtime is a compatible version?

Comment: Well, what do you **want** to happen when the wrong class version is used? I seriously doubt that you could do considerably better than throwing an error. At best you can influence *when* the error is thrown  (put the first access in a static initializer block and you'll make sure it happens when the class is loaded).

Comment: You would like to catch the error when the app initializes, e.g. "incompatible JAR" or something. You might be looking for a particular class version range. You might want to adapt your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just give my own answer then --

Java was not designed to determine at run-time whether the compile-time super class matches/is compatible with the run-time super class. Since Java uses separate class paths for building vs. running, and since subclasses do not replicate contents from the superclass, NoSuchFieldErrors are expected.

Java does not handle this out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out -

package com.mobilous.mail;

```
 import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
 import java.util.jar.Manifest;

public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Attributes> map = null;
    try {
        JarFile file = new JarFile("Your library file path");
        Manifest manifest = file.getManifest();
        System.out.println(manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Specification-Version"));
        System.out.println(manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Implementation-Version"));
        map = manifest.getEntries();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

now you should first check the file version of each jar file you need to check.if found older simply show an error message.

Comment: Using tools is not exactly what I am looking for -- I am looking for a general "correct" way of doing it according to what Java (the language & JVM) expects.